# Creating a Horizontal Funnel Chart in RShiny using Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I want to create a horizontal funnel chart in R Shiny. I have tried the orientation function but cant get it to work properly. Any help will be appreciated

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "funnel",
    y = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"),
    x = c(39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2)
    ) 
fig <- fig %>%layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent")))

fig
```

Comment: Will this work for you? `plot_ly() %>% add_trace(type = "funnel", orientation = "v", x = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"), y = c(39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2))`

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you so much